# How to convert integer numbers read from a text file and store as a binary file having 16bit integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, decimal

trying to read decimal values from text file convert into 16-bit binary and into a binary file.

Sample input file

```
120
300
-250
13
-120
```

Code:

```
def decimaltoBinary(filename,writefile):
    file = filename
    print(file)
    file_write = open(writefile,'wb')
    file_read = open(file, 'rb')
    for line in file_read:
        value = int(line)
        if value < 0:
            binary_value = bin((2**16) - abs(value))[2:].zfill(16)
            file_write.write(binary_value + "\n")
        else:
            binary_value = bin(int(value))[2:].zfill(16)
            file_write.write(binary_value + "\n")
    file_write.close()

decimaltoBinary(input_file.text,output_file.bin)
```

Hoping to write the converted decimal values into a binary file.. any help is much appreciated

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the `struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) for that:

```
data = [120,300,-250,13,-120] # you seem to have the reading part covered already
                              # using a list as data input for demo purposes
import struct

with open("f.bin","wb") as f: 
    for d in data:
        f.write(struct.pack('h', d)) # 2 byte integer aka short

with open("f.bin","rb") as f:
    print(f.read())  # b'x\x00,\x01\x06\xff\r\x00\x88\xff'
```

You just need to specify `'h'` to get short (2-byte integer) packing.

For the weird print output blame python - it replaces "known" `\xXX` codes with *shorter* normal characters - f.e. `',' => 0x2c` or `\r` => `\x0d` etc.